# Два URLLoader

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

Имеется вот такой код:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest('http://app.local/app.php?action=getName&vkid=' + id + '&rnd=' + Math.random());
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(request);
function onComplete(event:Event):void {
    // выводим полученные данные в поле имени
    vkname.text= 'Привет, ' + loader.data;
}
```

Можно ли как то сделать ещё один URLLoader? Если заменить все loader. на что то другое - получается ошибка Монтажный кадр 1, слой "Action", кадр 2, строка 25, столбец 11   1119: Обращение возможного неопределенного свойства text через ссылку со статическим типом flash.net:URLLoader .